# Regular Expression to removed unwanted characters from email

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the below code to remove some unwanted characters from the email. but the Regex replaces the '.' symbol, even though I did not mentioned in the character set to be removed.

```
string emailText = @"[\s;'\(\)\[\]!#\$%&\*\+-\?>=<_:\/\""]";
var stringInput = Console.ReadLine(); //Input "sara@gmail.com"
var stringTest = Regex.Replace(stringInput, emailText,string.Empty); //Output "sara@gmailcom"
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Saravanakumar R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the regexp, `\+-\?` means the range of ASCII characters between `+` and `?`, which includes lots of punctuation characters, including `.`.

You should escape the `-` to prevent it from meaning a character range. On the other hand, you don't need to escape most of the other special characters inside `[]`.

Comment: There is no `\+-\\ `, but `\+-\?`

Answer (score 4):

Move `-` to the beginning(or end) of the `[...]`.

`+-\?` cause all character between `+`(ASCII 43) and `?`(ASCII 63) to match.
`.`(ASCII 45) is included in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Minus(-) should also be escaped.

```
string emailText = @"[\s;'\(\)\[\]!#\$%&\*\+\-\?>=<_:\/\""]";
```